# Should known bugs be explicitly listed as "off-topic" in the FAQ scope?

Tags: discussion

See here, for example:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/51596/wordpress-does-not-return-404-when-the-url-is-changed

The OP *knows* that the behavior is a bug, and even links to the *Trac bug report he submitted*.

What value, then, does such a question provide for the WPSE community? Should such questions be considered off-topic, or should they be re-phrased to solicit work-around solutions in lieu of the bug report being closed/fixed?

Answer (score 6):

Asking for a workaround should be allowed. Some bugs are open for more than seven years, pointing to Trac doesn't help anyone in those cases.

And who knows – maybe we can come up with a solution that actually fixes the bug and finds its way into the core?

Comment: +1 for leaving it open. "finds it way into core"? Ha!

Comment: I'm cool with this, provided the emphasis is on *rewriting the question to that it is scoped to pertain to a **workaround** in lieu of a bugfix*.

Comment: Of course. Naked statements aren't good questions. If you think it is worth thinking about a workaround just **rewrite the question**. :)

Comment: I definitely agree. We all know the Wordpress development team are known for taking years to fix issues, I guess that's the beauty of open source software anyone can come up with a solution to a known bug.